# Wordpress - PHP Update Recommended

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

This is my situation. Any help would be gratefully received.

- Google Cloud
- Bitnami Wordpress
- Apache server
- Current PHP version 7.3.18

**What are the Linux commands to update PHP to version 7.4, or ideally 8?**

I have looked online and I'm nervous to follow some of the YouTube tutorials as they don't exactly fit my situation. They're also in Indian language which I don't speak.

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing with PHP, Apache, and Bitnami, you are stuck at 7.3. I recommend creating a new VM instance and setup LAMP without Bitnami. Back up WordPress and migrate to the new server. Your question needs a lot of details in order to answer correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John. I had a bad feeling that this might be the situation.

Comment: This does not look related to programming to me. Maybe serverfault.com is a better place to post this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check your php version : php-v.
Run this command : sudo apt-get update
One more command : sudo apt-get install php8.

You should be fine.

Comment: Switching a web server's PHP version requires more configuration steps. This answer will cause more problems than it solves.